# How to eliminate second item of a nested dictionary and skip the empty nested lists?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, nested

I am having issues eliminating the second item of the lists nested inside a list of dictionaries. I think it may be because there are a couple of empty lists, so the indexing does not work. **How can I delete the second item of each nested list pair but also skip the empty lists?**

In the end, the nested list should be flattened as it does not have a second pair anymore.

**The list looks something like this:**

```
list_dict = [{"name": "Ken", "bla": [["abc", "ABC"],["def", "DEF"]]}, 
             {"name": "Bob", "bla": []}, #skip the empty list
             {"name": "Cher", "bla":[["abc", "ABC"]]}]
```

**Desired output:**

```
wanted = [{"name": "Ken", "bla": ["abc", "def"]}, 
             {"name": "Bob", "bla": []}, 
             {"name": "Cher", "bla":["abc"]}]
```

**My code:**

```
for d in list_dict:
    for l in list(d["bla"]):
        if l is None:
            continue  #use continue to ignore the empty lists
        d["bla"].remove(l[1]) #remove second item of every nested list pair (gives error).
```

Comment: The last line is indented too much.

Comment: btw, I guess that `if l is None:` is never true since its always a `list` and never `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yu can use `[:1]` to get only first item from the list (works with zero-lenght lists too):

```
list_dict = [{"name": "Ken", "bla": [["abc", "ABC"],["def", "DEF"]]}, 
             {"name": "Bob", "bla": []}, #skip the empty list
             {"name": "Cher", "bla":[["abc", "ABC"]]}]


for i in list_dict:
    i['bla'] = [ll for l in [l[:1] for l in i['bla']] for ll in l]

print(list_dict)
```

Prints:

```
[{'name': 'Ken', 'bla': ['abc', 'def']}, 
 {'name': 'Bob', 'bla': []}, 
 {'name': 'Cher', 'bla': ['abc']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten lists using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

Example:

```
In [24]: l = [["abc", "ABC"],["def", "DEF"]]

In [25]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
Out[25]: ['abc', 'ABC', 'def', 'DEF']
```

After you flatten your list you can slice it to get every second element:

```
In [26]: flattened = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))

In [27]: flattened[::2]
Out[27]: ['abc', 'def']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work, even if a given `l` is empty:

```
for d in list_dict:
    d["bla"][:] = (v[0] for v in d["bla"])
```

For improved efficiency, you can extract `d["bla"]` once per entry:

```
for d in list_dict:
    l = d["bla"]
    l[:] = (v[0] for v in l)
```

This changes `list_dict` to:

```
[{'name': 'Ken', 'bla': ['abc', 'def']},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'bla': []},
 {'name': 'Cher', 'bla': ['abc']}]
```

Note that this solution does not create any new lists.  It simply modifies the existing lists.  This solution is more concise and more efficient than any of the other posted solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chain.from_iterable` like this example:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections.abc import Iterable

list_dict = [{'name': 'Ken', 'bla': [['abc', 'ABC'], ['def', 'DEF']]},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'bla': []},
 {'name': 'Cher', 'bla': [['abc', 'ABC']]}]

out = []
for k in list_dict: 
         tmp = {} 
         for key, value in k.items(): 
             # Check if the value is iterable
             if not isinstance(value, Iterable): 
                 tmp[key] = value 
             else: 
                 val = list(chain.from_iterable(value))[:1] 
                 tmp[key] = val 
         out.append(tmp)

print(out)

[{'name': 'Ken', 'bla': ['ABC', 'def', 'DEF']},
 {'name': 'Bob', 'bla': []},
 {'name': 'Cher', 'bla': ['ABC']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
list_dict = [{"name": "Ken", "bla": [["abc", "ABC"],["def", "DEF"]]}, 
             {"name": "Bob", "bla": []}, #skip the empty list
             {"name": "Cher", "bla":[["abc", "ABC"]]}]

desired_dict = [{"name": "Ken", "bla": ["abc", "def"]}, 
             {"name": "Bob", "bla": []}, 
             {"name": "Cher", "bla":["abc"]}]
```

You can simply recreate `d['bra']` to be what you want. The empty lists are skipped since there is nothing to iterate and the existing entry is unchanged:

```
for d in list_dict:
    d['bla']=[sl[0] for sl in d['bla']]

>>> list_dict==desired_dict
True
```